# How to load network image with redirect url?

Tags: flutter

i tried to load image from api,
when i use NetworkImage from flutter or CachedNetworkImage plugin, the app frezee and stop working with this error

> I/flutter ( 314): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
>   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════  I/flutter (
>   314): The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec: 
>   I/flutter ( 314): Exception: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 308, 
>   I/flutter ( 314): http://example.com/image/sample.jpg

code sample :

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                                "$assetsImages/loader_image.gif",
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                              ),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
                                "$assetsImages/image_unavailable.jpg",
                                height:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                              ),
                          imageUrl: restoImageUrl + value['filename'],
                        )
```

problem is on imageUrl: restoImageUrl + value['filename'],
when i click the link image of error its opened normally on browser,
how to fix this?
or how to make flutter support that url 308 permanently redirect?

Comment: did you solve it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

is your api working on the browser?

try with placeholder

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                  placeholder: "assets/images/logo.png",
                                  image:
                                      "$_url/nativeapi/v1.0/s3object/GetCompanyLogo?siteId=${widget.siteId}")
```

Comment: yes my api working on the browser, and the image load after SSl redirect,

Answer (score 0):

Still in Sep '20 there isn't a good solution where you can configure your own Http module with Flutter and pass it on through `Image.network()` or `NetworkImage()`.

There are a few libraries but they rather let you choose to `followRedirects: boolean` or add `headers: Map<String, String>` so you have to choose if you want Authentication or ability to redirection.

In my case, I was the owner of the API that was providing the redirection of the image. I realised I was using `PERMANENT_REDIRECT` (308) and it was working fine with Postman or browser, but what I did is changing the status code to MOVED_PERMANENTLY (301).

And it works now!